# How to toggle between two buttons and change color using angular

Tags: angularjs, toggle

I am trying to create two buttons, with both the buttons not selected on initial load. On clicking the first button, it gets selected and I am applying color for that. During initial load, the message displayed below the buttons is different from the one that is displayed after clicking the button . I have tried the logic to apply the color changes on toggle , but how do I deselect both the buttons on initial load and change the message appropriately.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/vo8tdROK9YafkS0FHdjy?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are some issues with your code:

- Really consider when using **!boolVariable**, try **boolVariable = false**.
- Conditional operator ( **bool ? return1 : return2** ) is used to return value, not to assign or apply logic.
- I'm not so sure there is syntax like this **ng-class="{true: 'green', false: 'blue'}[!yupNope.isSelected]"** (maybe i'm not awared of new syntax).

Here the modified example, please try if it's what you want

```
plnkr.co/edit/yvMgUaPN8NPgSYYiXAhI?p=preview
```

Comment: Thank you so much Phong. I am wondering how to change the message in span tag. On initial load, I need to have a message "Please select any one of the options" Once I select the option , the message should be replaced with , "Thank you for selecting". I have updated the plnkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/szZwIfoCc04Iwpv59cNz?p=preview

Comment: Hi Kate, try this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/LlTjhW48FQnwsRr3M69V?p=preview